# Pandas Add column based on dict value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe df, it contains the following columns : col1, col2, col3

Col1 contains string values (possible duplicate values) as shown :

```
Val1
Val2
Val3
Val1
Val1
Val1
```

Additionally, I have a dictionary storing mapping of Col1 -> new values that I need to add to the dataframe 'df'.
Example :

```
{
    "Val1" : "new_val1",
    "Val2" : "new_val2",
    "Val3" : "new_val3",
}
```

Now, based on the dictionary mapping, I want to add 'col_new' to the 'df'. Sample final dataframe (showing only relevant columns) :

```
col1  col_new
Val1  new_val1
Val2  new_val2
Val3  new_val3
Val1  new_val1
Val1  new_val1
Val1  new_val1
```

I tried df.map(), but that seems to only work when the key column in dataframe is unique.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick, use `map`:

```
your_dict={
    "Val1" : "new_val1",
    "Val2" : "new_val2",
    "Val3" : "new_val3",
}

df['col_new'] = df['col1'].map(your_dict)
```

which `prints` your desired output:

```
   col1   col_new
0  Val1  new_val1
1  Val2  new_val2
2  Val3  new_val3
3  Val1  new_val1
4  Val1  new_val1
5  Val1  new_val1
```

Comment: df['col_new'] = df['col1'].map(your_dict) line returns the error :

File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 3983, in map
    new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 1160, in _map_values
    new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2403, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

Comment: Strange that it's not working, I use this command almost every day. It runs perfectly on mine. What ```pandas``` and ```python```  version do you have?

Comment: It was an issue at my end, I did not define my dictionary properly; any way to mark this question as invalid ?  (P.S. thanks for the help)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @sophods
you can also

```
df['col_new'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x:your_dict[x])
```

*Added based on comment*

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Val1','Val2','Val3','Val1','Val1','Val1']})
your_dict={
    "Val1" : "new_val1",
    "Val2" : "new_val2",
    "Val3" : "new_val3",
    }

df['col_new'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x:your_dict[x])
print(df)
```

output

```
   col1   col_new
0  Val1  new_val1
1  Val2  new_val2
2  Val3  new_val3
3  Val1  new_val1
4  Val1  new_val1
5  Val1  new_val1
```

Comment: df['col_new'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x:your_dict[x]) returns the error :
File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4213, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2403, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "cn.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    df['col_new'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x:your_dict[x])
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I have added the full code, in which I get result - welcome.